# How do I make catch2 not print its annoying header?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, command-line-interface, catch2

I'm running some unit tests built with catch2. Its output begins with:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_suite is a Catch v2.13.6 host application.
Run with -? for options
```

well, I don't want to see that. Neither I nor other users/maintainers need to be reminded of the catch2 version or of the ability to run with `-?`, when we ran the unit test with proper arguments and know what we're doing.

But - the `-?` options don't seem to tell me how to disable this message. Can I? Or do I have to manually "bastardize" the catch2 header?

Comment: Another workaround could be to pipe the output through a program that cuts out the first few lines.

Comment: @eerorika: I'm not writing a custom script and telling people to run that rather than the actual unit test. Grrr.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see any value for it in a Q and A format. Someone would come with the same question later? Doubtful. The tone is also a bit abrasive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch2 is open-source

If you go to `src/catch2/reporters/catch_reporter_console.cpp`, you'll find:

```
void ConsoleReporter::lazyPrintRunInfo() {
    stream << '\n' << lineOfChars('~') << '\n';
    Colour colour(Colour::SecondaryText);
    stream << currentTestRunInfo->name
        << " is a Catch v" << libraryVersion() << " host application.\n"
        << "Run with -? for options\n\n";
```

Just remove this last line. It should not break anything and fix your issue.

Alternatively, you can edit `src/catch2/interfaces/catch_interfaces_config.hpp` and add a configuration option, `virtual bool printHeader();` and submit a PR. This config is used just the line after printing the header, so it is available.

Comment: I was worried that might be the answer :-(